# procedure dont receive char data in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

This procedure help us to make a little easier to add registers to our database

I have 4 variables declared outside the procedure(id_usuario, des, monto, id_tipo)
id_usuario,monto and id_tipo are integers and des is char
The main problem is that if i print des variable in the cmd it show me a value but if i print it in the procedure it says is null

Any ideas??

```
delimiter //
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE reg_egresos(IN id_usuario INT,IN descripcion CHAR(50),IN monto INT, IN id_tipo INT)
BEGIN   
    insert into Egresos values(null, @descripcion, @monto, CURDATE(), 1, 
    @id_tipo);  
END; // 
delimiter ;


call reg_egresos(@id_usuario, @des, @monto, @id_tipo);
```

Comment: please do a search before asking a question, it will save you time 90% of the time

Comment: I read the other post but it is completely different